# Replace commas, full stops, hyphens, and spaces with underscore

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace commas, full stops, hyphens, and spaces with underscores. I have tried the below but get the error `Range out of order in character class`

```
'Helo,._cool '.replace(/[,.- ]/g, "_")
```

Comment: `.- ` is being interpreted as a range from `.` to a space, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `-` character, because it's used to specify a range of characters like `0-9` or `a-z`.

```js
console.log('Helo,._cool '.replace(/[,.\- ]/g, "_"));
```